# Unable to use std::shared_ptr as value type in std::map?

Tags: c++11, dictionary, shared-ptr

I have the following class which I want to add to a `map` as a `shared_ptr`.

```
struct texture_t
{
hash32_t hash;
uint32_t width;
uint32_t height;
uint32_t handle;
};
```

So I try and use `make_pair` and then add it to the `map`...

```
auto texture = std::make_shared<texture_t>(new texture_t());
std::make_pair<hash32_t, std::shared_ptr<texture_t>>(hash32_t(image->name), texture);
```

And on `make_pair`, I receive the following compile error:

```
error C2664: 'std::make_pair' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> &&'
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::make_pair` isn't intended to be used with explicit template parameters.   Just leave them off:

```
auto my_pair = std::make_pair(hash32_t(image->name), texture);
```

NOTE: the call to make_shared is wrong as well.  The parameters are passed to the constructor of `texture_t`, so in this case it would just be:

```
auto texture = std::make_shared<texture_t>();
```

Comment: The call to `make_shared` is also wrong. This has been fixed in [a follow-up question by OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433712/trouble-constructing-shared-ptr/), but might be worth mentioning here for completeness.

Comment: And you could just use `.emplace` to insert the pair to the map without manually constructing it. `map.emplace(hash32_t(image->name), std::make_shared<texture_t>())`.