# Trouble constructing shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, make-shared

I'm new to smart pointers, and I'm in the process of hitting every stumbling block.

I have a struct `texture_t`:

```
struct texture_t
{
    hash32_t hash;
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
    uint32_t handle;
};
```

When I try and make a `shared_ptr` of this struct using this line:

```
auto texture_shared_ptr = std::make_shared<texture_t>(new texture_t());
```

I get this error:

```
error C2664: 'mandala::texture_t::texture_t(const mandala::texture_t &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'mandala::texture_t *' to 'const mandala::texture_t &'
```

Where is this error coming from and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to pass a `new`ed pointer to [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). You just need to pass arguments from which a `texture_t` can be constructed to it.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you.  Looks like these things are smarting than I thought!

Answer (score 4):

The point of `std::make_shared<T>(args...)` is to allocate a `T` object constructed with parameters `args...`. The idea behind this operation is that `std::shared_ptr<T>` conceptually maintains two allocated objects:

1. A pointer to type `T`.
2. A record tracking the number of current `std::shared_pt<T>` and the number of `std::weak_ptr<T>` objects referring to the object.

When constructing a `std::shared_ptr<T>` the constructor does a second allocation to construct the record for its internal book keeping. `std:make_shared<T>(args...)` does just one memory allocation.

The error you saw results from an attempt to construct a `mandala::texture_t` using a `mandala::texture_t*` but the only one argument constructor `mandala::texture_t` has is the copy constructor. However, the pointer doesn't qualify as argument to the copy constructor.